# Showing img in django admin

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-admin

i was trying to show image in django admin. i try this code

> admin.py

```
@admin.register(SampleImages)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['image_tag']
```

and for **models.py**

```
class SampleImages(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/tile_images')

    def image_tag(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="{}" width="150" height="150"/>'.format(self.image))

    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
```

but image is not showing, i inspect html and that fine.

```
<img src="images/tile_images/150x150.gif" width="150" height="150">
```

in django admin when i click image url it say

> Sample images with ID "1/change/images/tile_images/150x150.gif"
>   doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?

And image is present in my **images/tile_images** folder. 
Anyone can help please?.

Comment: It sounds like your project might not know where to look for the images.  Do you have you settings.py file media URL's setup correctly?  Check out the [link managing static files documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)?

Comment: @Dilshad can you confirm whether the uploaded image file actually exists on disk, in the `MEDIA_ROOT/images/tile_images` folder?

Comment: i have these setting for MEDIA `MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")` and **url.py** `urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` my images reside in project **base dir/media/images/tile_images**

Comment: @2091925 sir how to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you output the src of the image, make sure you use the url attribute of the image field:

```
return mark_safe('<img src="{}" width="150" height="150"/>'.format(self.image.url))
```

That will ensure that the URL correctly points at where the images reside in the MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: @2091925 it show me following error **[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "E:\\Study\\Projects\\Graphicdesign3\\('E:\\Study\\Projects\\Graphicdesign3\\media',)\\images\\tile_images\\150x150.gif**

Comment: @Dilshad in your `settings.py` do you have a trailing comma after the `MEDIA_ROOT` setting? The error indicates that your `MEDIA_ROOT` is a tuple, not a string.